# How to express OR conditions with the CakePHP 3.x query builder?

Tags: php, cakephp, conditional-statements, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to build a query in cakephp 3.X with the following structure :
 A and B and C and [D or E] where A,B, C, D, E contains an array of values joined with OR conditions like

```
$schools = $schools->where(['A  IN' => $arrayOfAOptions]), 
$schools = $schools->where(['B IN' => $arrayOfBOptions]),
$schools = $schools->where(['C IN' => $arrayOfCOptions])

// want this to be firstly joined with OR before joining other conditions with AND
$schools = $schools->where(['D IN' => $arrayOfCOptions]) 
//or
$schools = $schools->where(['E IN' => $arrayOfCOptions])
```

the problem here is that , I could not get fields D and E to be isolated as OR and join others with AND

in cakephp 2, i managed to achieve it with the following codes

```
$queryConditions = array(
  'or'=> array_merge(
    array(
      'School.D' =>  $this->Session->read('conditions.D')
    ), 
    array(
      'School.E' => $this->Session->read('conditions.E')
    )
  )
);
```

before merging it to the rest on the conditions 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: We live in 2017, you should use `['key' => 'value']` instead of ancient `array()` as it helps a lot with formatting (unless you need backwards compatibility (talking PHP < 5.4 here, ancient and should be forgotten)). As to your question it seems solid and I don't have the answer for you. But an upvote for you as you've done your research.

Comment: that was just to let you know what i did before migrating to cake 3.0 and php 7

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same style as in CakePHP 2.x, ie pass your conditions nested under the `OR` key. You can also wrap this in a single `where()` call.

```
$schools->where([
    'A IN' => $arrayOfAOptions,
    'B IN' => $arrayOfBOptions,
    'C IN' => $arrayOfCOptions,
    'OR' => [
        'D IN' => $arrayOfDOptions,
        'E IN' => $arrayOfEOptions
    ]
]);
```

You could also use `orWhere()`, but [**it has been deprecated**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/10885) lately as its behavior is a kinda fragile.

Finally, you can use expressions to create complex conditions. The `or_()` expression method can be used to create `OR` conditions:

```
$schools->where(function ($expr) use ($arrayOfAOptions, $arrayOfBOptions) {
    return $expr->or_([
        'A IN' => $arrayOfAOptions,
        'B IN' => $arrayOfBOptions,
    ]);
});
```

See also **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**